# jQuery mouseover function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, visibility

I have a problem with jQuery. I am trying to make an image appear(or fade in) upon onmouseover event and disappear(or fade out) upon onmouseout event. The HTML that I have is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<img id="mainImg" src="..." />
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#mainImg
{
visibility:hidden;
}
```

And the JavaScript is as follows:

```
$("#mainImg").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).attr("visibility", "visible");
  }).mouseout( function () {
    $(this).attr("visibility", "hidden");
  });
```

But this code does not work. I am struggling to understand what is wrong but I cannot sort it out. I tested the code also in JsFiddle with no result. I also tried with the hover() function without success.

May you please tell me what I am doing wrong and propose a solution? Thanks

Francesco

Comment: You could also use `hover(function() { //onmouseover }, function() { //onmouseout });`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visibility is not an HTML attribute; it's a CSS feature. Try using css() instead of attr().

Comment: Yep and I would instead use : `$(this).css("display","block")` and `$(this).css("display","none")`

Comment: You can change the `opacity` to 0 instead of changing the `visibiliy`. This is not exactly the same behavior but it's a workaround. [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/GaNAb/10/)

Comment: Apparently mouseover doesn't work on invisible objects... Didn't know that. If you change your CSS so that div.left is initially visible, it works once when you mouseout and then stops working. So I guess Sylvain's workaround is a good option here.

Comment: @Sylvain Thrd: thanks, your example works perfectly. Apparently setting the opacity is a less consuming operation for the script because the response time on the events (onmouseover and onmouseout) is faster than setting the visibility! Do you know if there is any specific reason?

Answer (score 2):

Find working sample here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ezmilhouse/MegL9/1/

you will run into problems if triggering events on invisible elements, better attach event to .wrapper:

your js:

```
$(".wrapper").mouseover(function () {
    $('img', this).css("visibility", "visible");
});

$(".wrapper").mouseout(function () {
    $('img', this).css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

your html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img id="mainImg" src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. Your solution works but sometimes the image gets stuck in "visibility:hidden" evne if I am mouseover. Does it depend on the size of the wrapper?

Comment: yes, basically you don't need it to have fixed width, height - updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezmilhouse/MegL9/4/, plz accept if it helped solve your prob, thx

Answer (score 2):

Actually the correct way to do that is using [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function.
Something like this:

```
$("#mainImg").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).toggle();
  }).mouseout( function () {
    $(this).toggle();
  });
```

Or using [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) / [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/), like this:

```
$("#mainImg").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).hide();
  }).mouseout( function () {
    $(this).show();
  });
```

The cool thing about doing it this way is that you can specify animations for the visible / invisible transitions.

Cheers!

Comment: You can also accomplish that with pure CSS (no Javascript at all) using the :hover selector.